# How to simplify several similar collection files in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm new in programming.

In VB2005, I have some object files, like a.vb, b.vb, c.vb.. each of them has different properties.

Then I have the collection files, for example: as.vb is the collection of a, bs.vb is the collection of b... each has mostly the same content, like add, item, count...

So now I would like to know, is that if it's possible to simplify these redundant collections, like integrating all into one single collection file but can be used by all the object files.

Thank u very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564.aspx) in .NET 2.0 onwards.

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/23/Collections.aspx) describes the various generic collections available in .NET 2.0

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is how you needed to do things to get a strongly typed collection in VB6.  .Net provides at least 3 different superior alternatives:

- Only have one generic *s.vb file that implements exactly the operations you want:

.

```
Public Class MyTypedCollection(Of T)
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.Collection(Of T)

    Public Overrides Sub Add(ByVal item As T)
       Mybase.Add(item)
    End Sub

    ''// ...
End Class
```

- Use or Inherit from the pre-built `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)`
- Use a pre-built List(Of T), but alias it so it has your own custom type name:

.

```
 Imports ACollection = System.Collections.Generic.List(Of A)
```